# Google provides 2 different examples of HttpURLConnection usage - Should we call HttpURLConnection's disconnect, or InputStream's close?

Tags: android

Google is providing 2 different examples of `HttpURLConnection` usage.

## Calling `InputStream`'s `close`

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

```
// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
// the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string.
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

---

## Calling `HttpURLConnection`'s `disconnect`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

---

For **resource leakage** and **performance consideration** (Need not to setup network connection from ground up, as my app will communicate with same server most of the time), should we

1. Call `HttpURLConnection`'s `disconnect` only.
2. Call the `InputStream`'s `close` only.
3. Call both `HttpURLConnection`'s `disconnect` & `InputStream`'s `close` (Haven't seen such official example so far).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Oracle's Java, calling the [`disconnect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29) may close the underlying socket connection, if the connection is idle (not fetching anything). This "indicates that other requests to the server are unlikely in the near future" using that same `HttpUrlConnection` instance. You will have to reopen a new socket connection by creating another `HttpUrlConnection`.

However, Google has modified `HttpUrlConnection` so that socket connections can be reused. In Android, the underlying `Socket` used by a `HttpUrlConnection` may be persisted and reused for multiple requests. If you call `disconnect` after completing your request, it may send the socket to a pool containing other idle connections, ready to be reused. The system does this to reduce latency.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29):

> Unlike other Java implementations, this will not necessarily close
>   socket connections that can be reused. You can disable all connection
>   reuse by setting the http.keepAlive system property to false before
>   issuing any HTTP requests.

So you should call `disconnect` to release resources (streams and sockets), but some of the resources released *may* be reused (i.e. the socket will go into a pool of idle sockets, ready for the next `HttpUrlConnection` instance to reuse it).

As for why the first example did not call `disconnect()`, that is the Java SE way of reusing the connection (I think, it's been a while). What the author did was manually close the `InputStream` of the connection and left the socket open and idle for reuse. The second example shows the correct way on Android.

**In summary**: calling `disconnect()` on Android will close any `InputStream` or `OutputStream` used for the connection and *may* send the socket used for the connection to a pool, ready to be reused for other requests. So, if you call `disconnect()`, there is no need to call `InputStream#close()`.

Comment: Is there any test/experiment I can conduct to confirm on calling `disconnect` is the right way?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng It depends on what you want to test for. If you want to test that `disconnect()` does release resources, take a look at [Android test sources for UrlConnection](http://goo.gl/w7K7LK). In particular, check the end of the test methods [`test_getContent()`](http://goo.gl/K3s2dN) and [`test_getContentStream()`](http://goo.gl/f9TdKE). These show that the streams are indeed expected to be closed after a call to `disconnect()`.

Answer (score 3):

Both `close` and `disconnect` method release the connection if not yet released with following 2 differences:

1. `close` method throws `IOException`. Hence in first example, the enclosing method `downloadUrl's` signature has `throws IOException`. Where as `disconnect` method does not throw any exception.
2. Calling `close` method ensures that any future references made to the closed connection such as `read` operation, will result in `IOException`.

The most important design fact about `Android's HttpURLConnection` implementation is :

> Connection is held when the last byte of the response is consumed. 
>   When the response if fully read, the connection is released and will
>   be pooled immediatetly.

You can see in the below image, variable `connection` & `connectionReleased` are set to `null` and `true` respectively, as soon as all data is read. In this case calling `disconnect` makes no difference, calling `close` just ensures future calls on closed connection throws `IOException`.

[image]

If data is still available on the `InputStream`, `close` or `disconnect` has to be called to release the connection explicitly. In this case the connection is **not reused** and underlying socket connection is also closed. This is done in anticipation that more data may arrive on the InputStream.

You can see in below code snippets, both `disconnect` and `close` will finally invoke `httpEngine.release(false)`, which will close the connection without adding to the connection pool.

[disconnect](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java) implementation:

```
@Override public final void disconnect() {
        // Calling disconnect() before a connection exists should have no effect.
        if (httpEngine != null) {
            httpEngine.release(false);
        }
    }
```

[close](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/FixedLengthInputStream.java) implementation:

```
@Override public void close() throws IOException {
    if (closed) {
        return;
    }
    closed = true;
    if (bytesRemaining != 0) {
        unexpectedEndOfInput();
    }
}
```

[unexpectedEndOfInput](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/AbstractHttpInputStream.java) implementation:

```
protected final void unexpectedEndOfInput() {
    if (cacheRequest != null) {
        cacheRequest.abort();
    }
    httpEngine.release(false);
}
```

[release](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpEngine.java) implementation:

```
public final void release(boolean reusable) {
    // If the response body comes from the cache, close it.
    if (responseBodyIn == cachedResponseBody) {
        IoUtils.closeQuietly(responseBodyIn);
    }
    if (!connectionReleased && connection != null) {
        connectionReleased = true;
        // We cannot reuse sockets that have incomplete output.
        if (requestBodyOut != null && !requestBodyOut.closed) {
            reusable = false;
        }
        // If the headers specify that the connection shouldn't be reused, don't reuse it.
        if (hasConnectionCloseHeader()) {
            reusable = false;
        }
        if (responseBodyIn instanceof UnknownLengthHttpInputStream) {
            reusable = false;
        }
        if (reusable && responseBodyIn != null) {
            // We must discard the response body before the connection can be reused.
            try {
                Streams.skipAll(responseBodyIn);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                reusable = false;
            }
        }
        if (!reusable) {
            connection.closeSocketAndStreams();
            connection = null;
        } else if (automaticallyReleaseConnectionToPool) {
            HttpConnectionPool.INSTANCE.recycle(connection);
            connection = null;
        }
    }
```

Summary :

- Connection is automatically released to the connection pool as soon as the last byte of the response is consumed.
- If the `IOException` will be handled by method operating on `InputStream`, use `disconnect`. If the `IOException` will be handled by the caller of the method operating on `InputStream`, use `close`. Remember `close` ensures `IOException` is thrown when `read` operation is performed on closed connection in future.